# Mocha test setup to run two tests who require same beforeEach setup

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, electron

I'm testing an Electron app using Spectron, using mocha to run the test suite.
I'm trying to accomplish running two tests that require the same setup, so I'm using beforeEach to achieve the repeated setup code.
The former tests runs successfully through as expected, but the second test bails out two early with error message:

`Error: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.`

I have achieved desired result if I add sleep function, but I'd rather not do that, any idea what could be the problem here?

```
const helpers = require('./global-setup')
var fs = require('fs')
var assert = require('assert')
const path = require('path');
var expect = require('chai').expect
//const chai = require('chai');

var describe = global.describe
var it = global.it
var beforeEach = global.beforeEach
var afterEach = global.afterEach


describe('Launch application', function () {
  helpers.setupTimeout(this)

  var app = null

  function snapshotOnError(picName) {
    console.log('taking error snapshot pic')
    app.browserWindow.capturePage().then(function (imageBuffer) {
      fs.writeFile(picName + '.png', imageBuffer)
    })
  }

  beforeEach(function () {
    return helpers.startApplication({
      args: [path.join(__dirname, '..')]
    }).then(function (startedApp) { app = startedApp });
  })

  afterEach(function () {
    return helpers.stopApplication(app)
  })

  describe('log into training mode', function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
      app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded()
        .browserWindow.focus()
        .getWindowCount().should.eventually.equal(1)
        .browserWindow.isMinimized().should.eventually.be.false
        .browserWindow.isDevToolsOpened().should.eventually.be.false
        .browserWindow.isVisible().should.eventually.be.true
        .browserWindow.isFocused().should.eventually.be.true
        .click('//*[@id="js-side-nav"]/div[1]/ul/li[1]')
        .electron.clipboard.writeText('training')
        .click('#username')
        .webContents.paste()
        .waitForValue('#username', 1000)
        .electron.clipboard.writeText('12345')
        .click('#password')
        .webContents.paste()
        .waitForValue('#password', 1000)
        .click('//*[@id="main"]/section/div[2]/form/div[4]/button')
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log('errorJ: ' + err)
          snapshotOnError('log_in_traning');
          //done(err)
        })
        .then(function() { done(); })
    })

    it('checks the text in left topbar menu', function() {
      return app.client
        .getText('#js-top-nav > div.nav-left > ul > li:nth-child(1) > span').should.eventually.equal('Actions')
        .getText('#js-top-nav > div.nav-left > ul > li.nav-news > span').should.eventually.equal('News')
        .getText('#js-top-nav > div.nav-left > ul > li:nth-child(3) > span').should.eventually.equal('Reports')
        .getText('#js-top-nav > div.nav-left > ul > li:nth-child(4) > span').should.eventually.equal('Settings')
        .getText('#js-activate-help-menu > span').should.eventually.equal('Help')
        done()
    })

    it('checks if icons in the top bar menu are present', function(){
      return app.client
        .isExisting('#js-top-nav > div.nav-left > ul > li:nth-child(1) > i').should.eventually.be.true
        .isExisting('#js-top-nav > div.nav-left > ul > li.nav-news > i').should.eventually.be.true
        .isExisting('#js-top-nav > div.nav-left > ul > li:nth-child(3) > i').should.eventually.be.true
        .isExisting('#js-top-nav > div.nav-left > ul > li:nth-child(4) > i').should.eventually.be.true
        .isExisting('#js-activate-help-menu').should.eventually.be.true
        done()
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to explicitly call the beforeEach hook in your first test.

Your beforeEach hook will run before each describe

Test runner will run the hooks by itself.